# Unwind Segue doesn't work when navigating through container views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

My app is made of a rootViewContoller that contains a Container View. However, i do push another view controllers through the container view. I wanted to unwind segue from a view controller to the root viewController, but it's not working. First here is a an image of the storyboard structure of the app:
[image]

Therefore, it's mainly a UINavigationController. The RootViewController contains a container view. From the first ViewController being viewed, i can push other view controllers.However the problem is, at some point i want to unwind right to RootViewController or the first container view, when i implement the unwind segue it doesn't segue. To implement the segue i first create an IBAction method at DemoViewController or DemoThreeViewController (i tried both). From the view controller that i want to segue from I ctrl + drag to the Exit button and chose the method i previously created for segueing. I added an identifier for the unwind segue through the inspector. When i want to unwind, I perform the segue. Long story short, it doesn't unwind. I've tried unwind segue without the container view and it works whereas with container view it doesn't. How can I fix that?

Comment: Not sure about using unwind segues, but have you tried the old approach of using [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]?

Comment: @kentoh thanks i don't know why i didn't think about that. please type it in down there so that i can reward you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about unwind segues, but you can try popping the view controllers from the navigation stack, the old way:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```